# Error in ./configure step. (CentOS 7) Your compiler does not have the necessary C++17 support

Tags: centos, g++, configure

The lower part is as follows.
How do we solve this?

```
checking whether the g++ linker (/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for g++ option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
checking if g++ PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
checking if g++ static flag -static works... no
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if g++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the g++ linker (/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++17... no
checking whether C++ compiler accepts -std=c++20... no
configure: error: Your compiler does not have the necessary C++17 support! Cannot proceed.
```

Comment: Update to a more recent compiler?

Comment: What does `g++ --version` say? What software is the configure part of?

Comment: How do I update with the latest compiler?

Comment: this is a g++ version .
g++ (GCC) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and tried everything out. At the end i found the solution in this thread ->
[g++: error: unrecognized '-std=c++17' (what is g++ version and how to install)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60336940/g-error-unrecognized-std-c17-what-is-g-version-and-how-to-install)

```
yum install devtoolset-10-gcc-c++
scl enable devtoolset-10 bash
make
exit
```